# I want to use a list in a for loop code. list[[i]] works fine, but why doesn't res <- vector("list",n) work?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am using a `for loop` to loop through two different matrices. The code looks like this:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1806),7,258)
x2 <- matrix(rnorm(1032),4,258)

samp_size <- 3
iter <- 1000
subs <- matrix(sample(1:nrow(x), samp_size*iter, replace=T),
               ncol=samp_size, byrow=T)
subs2 <- matrix(sample(1:nrow(x2), samp_size*iter, replace=T),
                ncol=samp_size, byrow=T)

for(j in 1:nrow(subs)){
  ad <- x[subs[j,],]
  ad1 <- x2[subs2[j,],]
  rd <- rbind(ad,ad1)
  dis <- dist(rd, method="euclidian")
  #CV <- sd(unlist(rd), na.rm=TRUE)/mean(unlist(rd), na.rm=TRUE)*100
  dis2 <- dis[dis!=0]
  list[[j]] <- mean(dis2)
  l <- unlist(list)
  l <- na.omit(l)
  sdis <- dist(ad, method="euclidian")
  sdis2 <- sdis[sdis!=0]
  res <- vector("list", 1000)
  res[[j]] <- mean(sdis2)
  l2 <- unlist(res)
  l2 <- na.omit(l2)
}
```

`list[[j]]` works just fine.

The result of each iteration is added to it as a list element based on the value of `j`.

However, `res[[j]]` ends up being full of `NULL` with only the last element containing a value.

I am not sure what is happening here. I would like `res[[j]]` to behave the same way as `list[[j]]` does.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you initialize `list`?  where as you are initializing `res` inside the loop

Comment: The problem is that you initialise `res` on each iteration of the loop, so it will be wiped each time (other than the last)

Comment: @AndrewGustar right. So should I create the variable `res` outside the loop, and then use it inside the loop? Why doesn't the same happen with list[[j]]?

Comment: As @AndrewGustar pointed out, this is the problem `res <- vector("list", 1000)`. It resets `res` in each iteration. This is not the case for `list`. It is usually wise to initialize before the loop if possible, but I guess it depends on what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: @Antsushi Yes, just initialise it once, before the loop.  Your code doesn't initialise `list` at all (although it should), so it is not getting reset.

Comment: By the way, it is a good idea to avoid variable names like `list` that are also the names of R functions.  It often leads to confusion!

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! This should be basic knowledge in my head by now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe initialize `res`:

```
# before the loop
res <- rep(list(NA),nrow(subs))
# or in the loop
res <- rep(list(NA),1000) 
# or 
res <- list(numeric(1000))
```